# How to store access keys/private keys safely in database

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, private-key

So I have a situation where we need to provide services to a rural area through simple to use apps like chat bots and offline wallets. However, in the backend, every user upon registration gets a new key pair which acts as their access key to the API we use which provides the service. Essentially we are the middlemen.

I have been researching and not being able to come to a decision how to best store those private keys. The few approaches; along with pros and cons; I figured are as follows

First: cipher

1. let cipher = (secret_salt + user chat id/phone number)
2. store pvt key in database as aes256(privatekey, cipher)

Pros:

- fast
- cheap

Cons:

- secret salt is the only point of failure

Second: envelope encryption

1. Generate a main key encryption key using aws KMS
2. For every user, generate a data encryption key
3. Use the data encryption key to encrypt the users private key, and store that in database
4. Encrypt the data encryption key with the main key encryption key, and store that in database as well

Pros:

- can’t get private key from cloud KMS
- little slower

Cons:

- it attacker gets access to the application they can still simulate calls to aws?

I’m not sure if the second one is any better than the first, or if I should be considering different options altogether.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this question is too broad to be a good fit here, but I will share something that is definitely missing from it: a threat model. You haven't made clear what data you are trying to protect, who you are trying to protect it from, and how capable an adversary you are trying to thwart (e.g. no technical skill, script kiddie, determined cheapskate, national government intelligence agency). Are you trying to prevent freeloaders from using your paid services? Are you trying to protect your customers data from their adversaries?